# Ajax Not Loading Asynchronous. Refreshing Page when form submitted

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have been trying to learn ajax and from what I can see my code is correct however it always refreshes the page when it echo's the returned json string. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
  <script>      
    // Get XML HTTP Type
    function get_XmlHttp() {
        var xmlHttp = null;
            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        return xmlHttp;
    }

    function ajaxSuccess () {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }

    function ajaxrequest(oFormElement) {
        //Get The Correct XMLHTTP Object
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();             

        request.open(oFormElement.method, oFormElement.action, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.send(new FormData(oFormElement));
        return false;
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                alert("done");
                document.getElementById('comment_form').innerHTML = request.responseText;
            }
        }       
    }
    </script>


<form action="<?php echo $add_comment; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="comment_form" onsubmit="ajaxrequest(this);">
   <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
   <input name="user_message_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_message_id; ?>">
   <textarea id="new_comment" name="new_comment" cols="100" rows="5"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="post request"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I could be going blind, but where is the `submitForm()` function ?

Comment: I have actually tried it two ways one as in the example with the submit button and one with a link "<a onclick="submitForm(document.forms['comment_form']);" class="button"><?php echo $button_add_comment; ?></a>"

Comment: The problem is that your function does nothing to prevent the default action of the form submit button.

Comment: I am trying to build a comment system that works exactly like this one we are using.

Comment: How would I go about preventing the default action?

Comment: But you don't have a `submitForm()` function, it doesn't matter where you call it if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Ah to clarify I renamed submitForm() to ajaxrequest() I will adjust the question. Thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop the event from happening. there is a common used function this in javascript:

```
e.preventDefault; // e is the event that you need to pass to your function.
```

or Change
 `<input type="submit" value="post request"/>`
 to

```
<input type="button" onclick="ajaxrequest(this);" value="post request"/>
```

what is going to happen is your form is only going to be processed by javascript and page will mot reload due to the form submission.
Just modify this approach for yourself and it should fix your issue.

Comment: Justin, You are awesome that is exactly the problem. However an error shows up where I wanted the results to go. It was working on form submit now I get the error "GET to undefined not supported." is it still pulling in my form values?

Comment: I figured it out pretty simple really. My original code was just missing "return false;" in the form's onsubmit property. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery library http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, but if u wanna build your own script. consult w3c documentation http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: what I have is a variation of what they propose at W3schools.com. The issue I am having is since mine is a form it refreshes the page. I am nit sure how to keep it from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

As Pointy pointed out, you might want to prevent the default click event of the submit button from firing

```
submitForm( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

<strike>http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/</strike> <- My bad...

Just for clarification, is that your complete code?

Comment: No what I showed you was part of a TPL file that is being used inside of opencart.